# What's the difference between GNU_LIBC_VERSION and GNU_NPTL_VERSION?

Tags: redhat, ssl, nptl

Notice these two RedHat Linux system configuration settings:

```
$ getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
glibc 2.3.4

$ getconf GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION
NPTL 2.3.4
```

I see they correspond to some of the TLS libraries:

```
/lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so
/lib/tls/libm-2.3.4.so
/lib/tls/libpthread-2.3.4.so
/lib/tls/librt-2.3.4.so
```

I'd like to link against these libraries instead of the `/usr/lib` equivalents.  I have a few questions:

1. I've seen this on RedHat and Debian.  Does it exist on all GNU Linux distributions?
2. Is there any case where `GNU_LIBC_VERSION` differs from `GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION`?
3. Are those variables safe to use for identifying the shared libraries in `/lib/tls`?  I'd like to automate this in a Makefile, rather than hard-coding a magic glibc/pthread version number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The NPTL project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) which first implemented pThreads on Linux was a separate project initially adding kernel support and providing its own library.

When it was stable enough it was merged into glibc. I would assume that those two versions are identical on all reasonably up-to-date installations.

On Ubuntu 8.10 the output is like this:

```
$ getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
glibc 2.8.90
$ getconf GNU_LIBPTHREAD_VERSION
NPTL 2.8.90
```

Comment: Does your system have /lib/tls/libc-2.8.90.so?

Comment: No, but it's got /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.8.90.so.

Shouldn't it be the linkers job to find the correct version/location of that library?

Comment: It should be, but it sort-of isn't.  The linker will fild /usr/lib/libc.so, so it will resolve only the symbols found there.  But it will run against /lib/tls/..., so there are additional symbols available.  I have to jump through hoops to link against /lib/tls.

Comment: Though, I would think that /lib/tls/i686/cmov/ on your machine, and /lib/tls on my machine, would be programmatically defined from some other part of the environment (since it gets referenced for runtime resolution).  I just haven't figured that part out yet.